# Ruby is treating my variable as a comment

Tags: ruby

Full disclosure: I don't really know Ruby. I'm mostly faking it.

I have a script I want to use to gather inventory in Casper, which I'm using to manage a bunch of Macs. I'm attempting to pass a variable into a shell command with `%x`. Problem is, Ruby is treating the variable as a comment instead. Here is the relevant code:

```
def get_host
 host=%x(/usr/sbin/dsconfigad -show | /usr/bin/awk '/Computer Account/ {print $4}').chomp
 raise Error, "this machine must not be bound to AD.\n try again." if host == nil
end

def get_ou
  host = get_host
  dsout = %x(/usr/bin/dscl /Search -read /Computers/#{host}).to_a
  ou = dsout.select {|item| item =~ /OU=/}.to_s.split(",")[1].to_s.gsub(/OU=/, '').chomp
end
```

I tried using back ticks instead of `%x`, but got the same result. The command should return a bunch of information about the host it's run on, but instead it returns the result of `dscl /Search -read /Computers`, which is always `name: dsRecTypeStandard:Computers`.

How can I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Are you sure `get_host` isn't returning an empty string? Running the code within your `get_host` method on my Mac gives me `""` (granted, my machine is not part of a domain, but it returns an empty string instead of raising an error)

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Well, when I run it on a Mac that's on our AD, and add a `puts #{host}` in that method, it does return the AD hostname of the host. So I'm fairly sure that works, although it would be nice to know why it doesn't error out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here. The Ruby always returns the last expression in a method.

```
def get_host
  host=%x(/usr/sbin/dsconfigad -show | /usr/bin/awk '/Computer Account/ {print $4}').chomp
  raise Error, "this machine must not be bound to AD.\n try again." if host == nil
end
```

In this case, the last expression is:

```
raise Error, "this machine must not be bound to AD.\n try again." if host == nil
```

It will return the return value of `raise` (which don't gonna happen actually) if `host == nil` or will return `nil` if `host != nil`. So your method will never return something other than `nil`. Replace it by:

```
def get_host
  host=%x(/usr/sbin/dsconfigad -show | /usr/bin/awk '/Computer Account/ {print $4}').chomp
  raise Error, "this machine must not be bound to AD.\n try again." if host == nil
  host
end
```

Comment: As a side note, I think it is more idiomatic to use the nil? method when checking for the nil value e.g. `if host.nil?` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F

Comment: @sguha: If using `#nil?` beware `BasicObject` - these do not have `#nil?` and maybe used by libraries doing RPC and other interesting things. `BasicObject`'s do implement `==`, so that always works. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html

Comment: I just got a chance to try this out again today. It works! Thanks LBg!